# multilingual sparql

Tags: semantic-web, sparql

I want to query a triple store which is multilingual.

Query that works:

```
SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p "sdfsdf"@en}
```

I want "sdfsdf" to be an attribute in general like `?o@en`.

How should i query then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by the language of the object:

```
select * where { ?s ?p ?o . filter (lang(?o) = "en") }
```

Note that your results will be of the form `"sdfsdf"@en`, rather than just the lexical form `"sdfsdf"`. (You can do that additional work in SPARQL 1.1, and processors like ARQ using extensions)